# Drawing polar curve Lemiscate bug

Tags: c#, curve, polar-coordinates

I´m trying to draw a [lemiscate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate_of_Bernoulli). My code isn't drawing the curve correctly. Why does the line start or end at the point 0,0 (left corner)?

[image]

```
private void drawLemiscate(Graphics g, int a, int Sx,int Sy) 
{
    int x, y;


    Point[] p = new Point[720];
    for (int phi = 0; phi < 720; phi++)
    {
        int r = (int)(a * Math.Cos(2 * degreeToRadians(phi)));
        if (r > 0)
            continue;
        x = (int)Math.Round((r * Math.Sin(degreeToRadians(phi)) + Sx));
        y = (int)Math.Round((r * Math.Cos(degreeToRadians(phi)) + Sy));
        p[phi] = new Point(x, y);
    }
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
    g.DrawLines(pen, p);
    canvas.Invalidate();
}

private double degreeToRadians(double angle)
{
    return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate which element of `p` is (0, 0). You can use the debugger to inspect it or use a loop to look for it and print out which index(es) have (0, 0).

Hint: consider what effect `if (r > 0) continue;` has on your output.